# Filter query: Not null in elastic search

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

Currently I am working on Elastic Search 2.0 for my current Project. MySqL Query As follows,

select `user_id` from `users` where subscription_type ! = ''

In This above query, I Need to write in Elastic Search, I am trying in elastic search but it getting 
please find below code in elastic search

```
$query = array("from" => $start,
            "size" => $recordslimit,
            "sort" => array(array('id' => 'desc')),
            "query" => array(
                "filtered" => array(
                    "query" => array("match_all" => array()),
                    "filter" => array("bool" => array(
                            'must_not' => array(
                                array('term' => array('subscription_type' => ''))
                            )))
        )));
```

please help me out with this situation

Comment: See my answer maybe it helps. Just a reminder, it's much easier for us to help you if you post your mapping and a small set of documents so that we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible scenarios:

If subscription type is null or doesn't appear in your documents, then you can use  [missing query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-query.html) instead of a term query in the `must_not` clause.

On the other hand if you would like to exclude those documents whose `subscription_type` field holds the empty string, then your query is correct but maybe your mapping isn't. Make sure that `subscription_type` is defined as `not_analyzed` in the mapping.